# Creating new dataset by finding match in 2 other datasets in R

Tags: r

I've tried to be clear but apologies if it's not clear enough...I have two datasets of different length. In dataset 1, for col1 = x, col2 = y

dataset 1 =

```
col1  col2
0.1   0.21
0.1   0.22
0.2   0.4
0.34  0.3
0.4   0.36
```

Equally, in dataset 2, for col3 = x, col4 = y

```
col3  col4
0.1   0.2
0.2   0.3
0.3   0.4
0.4   0.5
0.5   0.6
0.6   0.7
0.7   0.8
```

Some values in col1 and col3 match so I would like to create a new dataset where all the values that are found in col1 are written (all the values found in col3 but not col1 are ignored) but with their "matching" number in col4 such that

```
new_col1 new_col4
0.1      0.2
0.1      0.2
0.2      0.3
0.34     NA
0.3      0.4
```

Could you please explain how I can do this? Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to say that my two datasets do not have the same number of decimals e.g. I have in col1 0.1, 0.1 etc and in col3 0.1111, 0.2222. Could you also tell me how to match col1 and col3 to within 1 number after the decimal, i.e. 0.1 matches 0.1111. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge`:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(col1=c(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.34,0.4),col2=c(0.21,0.22,0.4,0.3,0.36))
dat2 <- data.frame(col3=(1:7)/10,col4=(2:8)/10)

> merge(dat1, dat2, by.x="col1", by.y="col3", all.x=TRUE)[-2]
  col1 col4
1 0.10  0.2
2 0.10  0.2
3 0.20  0.3
4 0.34   NA
5 0.40  0.5
```

The `by` parameters specify which columns to match on, `all.x=TRUE` tells it to use all of the first dataframe, and the final subsetting `[-2]` is to remove `col2` from the output.

Edit:

For your extra requirement, use `dat2$col3 <- trunc(dat2$col3*10)/10` before the merge.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer! Regarding my problem with the decimal, your solution didn't work, probably because I didn't explain myself clearly. I used the solution suggestion in [link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/trunc-function-td3343170.html) by creating the following function `trunc.dig <- function(x, digits) trunc(x*10^digits)/10^digits`